# Silverlight-Compatible POP3 Library?

Tags: silverlight, pop3

Is there such a thing as a pop3 library compatible with Silverlight? I want to integrate a pop3 functionality into my application and I can't seem to find any library that is Silverlight-compatible.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a trusted Silverlight application, [MailBlackbox](http://ww.eldos.com/sbb/net-mail.php) package of our SecureBlackbox will do the job. If your application is not trusted, then [restrictions on network access, imposed by Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645032%28VS.95%29.aspx), will apply and will make your task much harder (but not impossible).